# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5000 with nextjs getserversideprops

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios

I am trying to connect to api on localhost:5000 which work perfectly when called from postman or the browser but does not work when called inside nextjs getserverside props:

```js
mport { useEffect,useState } from "react";
 import { GetStaticProps, GetStaticPaths, GetServerSideProps } from 'next'
 import Axios, {AxiosResponse} from 'axios'
interface Data{
    labels: string[],
    series:number[][]
}
function Chart(props) {
const [data,setData]= useState<Data>()
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(props)
 let fetchedData = {
    labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
    series: [
     [6,5,3,2,1]
    ]
  }
  
  setData(fetchedData)
    },[])
    
      
       new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data);
      useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          /* do stuff */
        }, );
      }, []);
    return (
        <>
        <div className="ibox ">
        <div className="ibox-title">
            <h5>Simple line chart
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div className="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
    </div>
        </>
        
    )
  }
  

  export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) =>{try {
    const res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/charts/2")
  
   let data= await res.data;
    return { props: { data } }
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    }}
     
export default Chart
```

and it return this error :

```js
  port: 5000,
  address: '::1',
  syscall: 'connect',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: -4078,
  path: '/api/charts/2',
  _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/api/charts/2',
```

I can not see any reason why it would not work espacially that it works in postman

Comment: Is `http://localhost:5000/api/charts/2` pointing to an external API endpoint, or is it an internal Next.js API route?

Comment: it is an endpoint of another api, but I solved the problem by upgrading my nodejs version
thank you

Answer (score 6):

## Node >= 18

### If you are using `node` version 18 or above and faced with this error in `build` or `getServerSideProps` for call `api` or etc:

```
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 8000
  }
```

In my case, I changed `api` address from `localhost:8000` `=>` `127.0.0.1:8000` and problem solved!

### DO NOT downgrade `node` to fix this!

Comment: thanks! I was facing a similar issue and this answer resolved that. Do you also know the reason why changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` worked?

Comment: Here is the reason https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40702#issuecomment-958143154